# ORACLE table performance basics

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, migration, database-administration

Complete newbie to Oracle DBA-ing, and yet trying to migrate a SQL Server DB (2008R2) to Oracle (11g - total DB size only ~20Gb)...

I'm having a major problem with my largest single table (~30 million rows).  Rough structure of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE TableW (
  WID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
  PID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
  CID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL
  ColUnInteresting1 NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
  ColUnInteresting2 NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
  ColUnInteresting3 FLOAT NOT NULL,
  ColUnInteresting4 FLOAT NOT NULL,
  ColUnInteresting5 VARCHAR2(1024 CHAR),
  ColUnInteresting6 NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
  ColUnInteresting7 NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL,
  CreatedDate  DATE NOT NULL,
  ModifiedDate DATE NOT NULL,
  CreatedByUser VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  ModifiedByUser VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
);

ALTER TABLE TableW ADD CONSTRAINT WPrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY (WID)
ENABLE;

CREATE INDEX WClusterIndex ON TableW (PID);
CREATE INDEX WCIDIndex ON TableW (CID);

ALTER TABLE TableW ADD CONSTRAINT FKTableC FOREIGN KEY (CID) 
REFERENCES TableC (CID) ON DELETE CASCADE
ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE TableW ADD CONSTRAINT FKTableP FOREIGN KEY (PID) 
REFERENCES TableP (PID) ON DELETE CASCADE
ENABLE;
```

Running through some basics test, it seems a simple 'DELETE FROM TableW WHERE PID=13455' is taking a huge amount of time (~880s) to execute what should be a quick delete (~350 rows). [query run via SQL Developer].

Generally, the performance of this table is noticeably worse than its SQL equivalent. There are no issues under SQL Server, and the structure of this table and the surrounding ones look sensible for Oracle by comparison to SQL.

My problem is that I cannot find a useful set of diagnostics to start looking for where the problem lies.  Any queries / links greatly appreciated.

[The above is a request for help based on the assumption it should not take anything like 10 minutes to delete 350 rows from a table with 30 million records, when it takes SQL Server <1s to do the same for an equivalent DB structure]

**EDIT:**
The migration is being performed thus:

```
1 In SQL developer:
    - Create Oracle User, tablespace, grants etc AS Sys 
    - Create the tables, sequences, triggers etc AS New User
2 Via some Java:
    - Check SQL-Oracle structure consistency
    - Disable all foreign keys
    - Move data (Truncate destination table, Select From Old, Insert Into New)
    - Adjust sequences to correct starting value
    - Enable foreign keys
```

Comment: Is there such thing in the Oracle as index fragmentation? If you created all your indices before loading the data and did not rebuild them after that, then chances are, the `WClusterIndex` index will be severely fragmented, to the point of being unusable.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I'm thinking of - please have a look at my edit to see if there are any obvious mistake made in the migration.

Comment: I don't know Oracle at all, but you can always try to drop and recreate the index. Best practice for any ETL is to drop indices before the load (on the destination side, of course) and create them after. It's not only faster but also keeps them less fragmented.

Comment: Did you gather statistics on the table? `exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLE_W');`

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli - Yes, and it made no difference to the execution time.

Comment: @Ennor - recreated all three main indexes, and still seems to have no effect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update all (and in case any else finds this):

The correct question to find a solution was: what tables do you have referencing this one?

The problem was another table (let's call it TableV) using WID as a foreign key, but the WID column in TableV was not indexed.  This means for every record delete in TableW, the whole of TableV had to be searched for associated records to be deleted.  As TableV is >3 million rows, deleting the small set of 350 rows in TableV meant the Oracle server trying to read a total of >1 billion rows.

A single index added to WID in TableV, and the delete statement now takes <1s.

Thanks to all for the comments - a lot of Oracle inner working learnt!

Answer (score 0):

If you ask us how to improve the performance, then there are several ways to improve it:

- [Parallel DML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/usingpe.htm)
- [Partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/toc.htm).

Parallel DML consumes all the resource you have to perform the operation. Oracle runs several threads to complete the operation. Other sessions has to wait for the end of the operation, because system resources are busy.

Partitioning let you exclude old sections right away. For example, your table stores the data from 2000 to 2014. Most likely you don't need old records, so you can split your table for several partitions and exclude the oldest one.

Comment: Improving performance is a secondary step - first I have to know if there is something wrong with the structure I have migrated...

Comment: What is the problem? Have you run your script? Did you see any errors?

Comment: Note added to initial question:
The above is a request for help based on the assumption it should not take more than 10 minutes to delete 350 rows from a table with 30 million records..

Comment: How can we know that? You can run your on the Intel celeron processor with 32MB memory or you can run it on one of the super computers. You have to try and then you will find out if it takes more than 10 minutes or not

Comment: See the problem statement:
I am migrating from SQL Server to Oracle.
I am running the query 'DELETE FROM TableW WHERE PID=13455' 
This query works fine under SQL Server (runs in <1s)
This query does not appear to work fine under Oracle (runs in >10min)

How can I diagnose the issue under Oracle?

Comment: Execute this query: `SELECT * FROM TableW WHERE PID=13455` How much time does it take?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN PLAN` to verify the expected indexes are begin used.  All other things being equal, I would not expect such a large difference in performance.

Comment: zaratustra - takes 0.059s to SELECT all 384 rows
@DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP:
|Id | Operation         | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
| 0 | DELETE STATEMENT  |   |  309 |  7107 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 1 |  DELETE           | W |      |       |            |       |
|*2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| WCLUSTER|   309 |  7107 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |


Hmmm... It is interesting the select (correctly) shows 384 rows, whereas the Plan only shows 309 rows.  Is there a hint here that something is wrong?

Comment: @zaratustra The select seems to run in a correct time: all rows retrieved in <0.1s.  In fact, all select queries using this table (even complex ones) seem to run faster than on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the wait events for your session that's doing the DELETE. That will tell you what your main bottleneck is.

And echoing Marco's comment above - Make sure your table stats are up to date - that will help the optimizer build a good plan to run those queries for you.

Comment: Table stats up to date, and largest value (number and total time) in V$SESSION_EVENT for the given session are for 'db file scattered read' (excluding the 'SQL*NET message from client').  This would imply the majority of the time spent is purely in reading the whole table, no? Why would that be, if the column is indexed?